# WordPress AJAX live search without jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, live

I'm trying to make ajax live search on WP website without usage of jQuery cause I don't want to load additional 80kb for this feature. I already made it work with jQuery, but when I try to rewrite script to work with Vanilla jS, I always got the issue

wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)

working code

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
    type: 'post',
    data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val() },
    success: function(data) {
        jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
    }
});
```

VANILLA JS CODE that doesn't work

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

request.onload = function () {
  if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
    console.log('if');
  } else {
    console.log('else');
  }
};

request.onerror = function() {
  console.log('onerror');
};

var data = document.getElementById('keyword').value;
request.send(data);
```

Comment: What is `data`? It needs to be a serialized string. EG: `'action=data_fetch&keyword=' + document.getElementById('keyword').value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious problem I see without knowing your problem is that `request.send(data);` does not equal to `{ action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val() }` instead you should be writing something like this `request.send('action=data_fetch&keyword='+data);`

Also, depending on the data value you are passing you may need to encode it. Again, it is somewhat hard to help you without knowing exactly the problem you are having.

Comment: That solved it. Thank you very much. Btw. I wrote which problem I had: "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)"